# fadeIn( ) does not use my css positioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

I am working on a site that only shows many items (images) that you can drag & drop. So far so good my **JS** is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).pep();
    });
</script>
```

The **HTML** is:

```
 <img class="draggable" id="item_1" onload="this.width/=2;this.onload=null;" src="http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/img/01.png"/>
```

And the **CSS** is:

```
 #item_1 {
   position: fixed;
   left: 300px;
   top: 150px;
   z-index: 2;
 }
```

That's the way I handle all the objects on the site… But if I want to add a fadeIn() to every item, so that they fadeIn one after the other… the JS does not care about my CSS positioning anymore… It fades in all objects at "`left: 0px; top: 0px`" …Why is that? How can I fix that?

That's my **JS** code with that fadeIn():

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".draggable").hide();
        $(".draggable").each(function(index) {
            $(this).delay(800).delay(50*index).fadeIn(400);
        });
    });

    $(function() {
        $( ".draggable" ).pep();
    });
</script>
```

Here you can get an impression:
http://www.cyrill-kuhlmann.de/play.html

Thank you for any help!

Comment: Perhaps the problem is that you're resizing the image `onload`, so it only appears to be in the wrong position? You should use CSS to resize images before they can load.

Comment: If I delete the onload resizing it does not do any change in the behaviour… I just can't figure out…

Comment: Yes the only thing that gets wrong is that the items get faded in at "top:0px; left:0px;" and not at the postion i gave them with my CSS

Comment: I'm afraid I can't see the problem using your code. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/w6auwLnz/) -- perhaps there's some interference from the `draggable` JS?

Comment: Yes the fadeIn() works right…but the drag & drop not… is that because the library is missing? strange…

Comment: The `draggable` JS is missing from my fiddle because you didn't say where you got it from.

Comment: here i guess:

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.pep/0.4.0/jquery.pep.min.js"></script>

Comment: The [latest version of `jquery.pep.js`](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js) has a `startPos` option, ***or*** it will auto-detect the `left` and `top` css properties. Either way, all you need is an upgrade to the plugin. http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/haskbkqz/1/

Answer (score 1):

The [latest version of `jquery.pep.js`](https://github.com/briangonzalez/jquery.pep.js) has a `startPos` option, ***or*** it will auto-detect the `left` and `top` css properties. Either way, all you need is an upgrade to the plugin.

http://jsfiddle.net/mblase75/haskbkqz/1/

Comment: I've tried… but the problem is either there's the correct fadeIn() (right position) but then the drag & drop does not work anymore … or there is fadeIn() and drag & drop but it fades in at left:0px and top:0px …what I am doing wrong :-)??????

Comment: I don't have enough code to answer that. It might be considered a new question, though. First you should always check the console for errors that are blocking the code from running.

Comment: I can't manipulate the code on your server. Please post a *minimal, complete* example here or on http://jsfiddle.net that *fully* represents the problem you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you can change the behavior of the fadeIn function.
What I would recommend instead is using **CSS Transitions**. You can set the default opacity to `opacity: 0` and then set a transition with `transition: opacity 200ms`.

Now you just need to apply a class to each of your element with a short delay in between, like this: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/smzoejkh/).